# Jquery plugin scope question (closures)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a plugin and am running into some problems:

```
(function($){
    var users = {};

    $.fn.plugin = function(){
        //blah, but alters users
    }
    $.fn.utility_function = function(){
        // uses users
    }
});
```

What's happening is that when I run two instances of this plugin, "users" ends up having the same value for each instance of the plugin. How do I make them unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's completely normal, because your users object lives outside the scope of your plugins.

I suggest you store the value as part of the data() jquery method attached to your dom element affected by the plugin

see [this article](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip14).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like unique objects, you can make a deep copy of an object with jquery's built in `extend` method.

In your case, you'd do:

```
(function($){
    var users = {};

    $.fn.plugin = function(){
        var myUsers = $.extend({}, users);
        //blah, but alters users
        // BUT should now use myUsers instead
    }
    $.fn.utility_function = function(){
        // uses users
    }
});
```

But I'm not sure you'd want unique copies of the users object, since they probably are a single set that probably only changes globally.